# Equivalence of logic propositions

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The statements:

1. $(p\wedge q)\rightarrow r$
2. $(p\rightarrow r) \vee (q\rightarrow r)$

are equivalent, as can be seen by constructing truth tables, or by applying a series of more elementary logical equivalences. I have verified this. However, I'm having trouble making sense of this in the context of an example. Namely, consider these statements about a natural number $n$:

- $p=$ $n$ is greater than $2$
- $q=$ $n$ is prime
- $r=$ $n$ is odd

In this case, it is true that $(p\wedge q)\rightarrow r$. "If $n$ greater than $2$ and prime, then $n$ is odd."

On the other hand, it is not the case that "($n>2$ implies $n$ odd) or ($n$ prime implies $n$ odd)". Neither of those is a true implication.

I must be interpreting statement 2 incorrectly, but I don't see how to make it right. Can anyone help me? Is this another case of the weirdness of material implication?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Looks good to me.(See my answer)

Comment: You can check this wikipedia article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxes_of_material_implication

Comment: The second example in the "simplification" section is equivalent to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a natural number $n$, then "($n>2$ implies  odd) or ( prime implies  odd)" is most definitely true, why? well suppose $n\le2$ then the statement is obviously true since ($n>2$ implies  odd) is true, now suppose $n> 2$ then the only way for the statement to be false if for the the conditions to be false, but if ($n>2$ implies  odd) is false, then $n$ must be even but that means that $n$ is prime is false(cause we assumed $n>2$) and so ( prime implies  odd) is true.

Answer (score 4):

If you add a "for all $n$" to both statements, you get that "$\forall n,(p(n)\land q(n))\to r(n)$" is equivalent to "$\forall n,((p(n)\to r(n))\lor(q(n)\to r(n))$". Your example shows that this is not equivalent to "$(\forall n, p(n)\to r(n))\lor (\forall n,q(n)\to r(n))$".

If you instead mean to talk about a particular fixed $n$, then the "$(p\to r)\lor(q\to r)$" in your example is indeed true, as the other answers have explained.

Comment: Funny that this answer got upvoted, while mine lying down below with zero votes, along with a nonsensical answer.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku I upvoted both, and wish I could accept both.

Answer (score 0):

let $p=q=r=n$.

either $n>2 \land n (mod 2)=0$ or $n \in P \land n (mod 2)=1$.
if $n>2$ then the second formula is true.